# Fatal error: Class 'Services_Twilio' not found

Tags: php, twilio

I'm trying to send a text message when a form is submitted using Twilio's test account however I'm receiving the following error: 'Fatal error: Class 'Services_Twilio' not found'

My code is as follows:

```
} else{
        //PHP native
        mail( $to_guest, $subject, $html_text, $header_guest);
        // Outlet Admin notification email
        mail( $to_admin, $subject, $notification_text, $header_admin);

/* Send an SMS using Twilio. You can run this file 3 different ways:
     *
     * - Save it as sendnotifications.php and at the command line, run 
     *        php sendnotifications.php
     *
     * - Upload it to a web host and load mywebhost.com/sendnotifications.php 
     *   in a web browser.
     * - Download a local server like WAMP, MAMP or XAMPP. Point the web root 
     *   directory to the folder containing this file, and load 
     *   localhost:8888/sendnotifications.php in a web browser.
     */

    // Step 1: Download the Twilio-PHP library from twilio.com/docs/libraries, 
    // and move it into the folder containing this file.
    require ('http://xzenweb.co.uk/reservation/web/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php');

    // Step 2: set our AccountSid and AuthToken from www.twilio.com/user/account
    $AccountSid = "";
    $AuthToken = "";

    // Step 3: instantiate a new Twilio Rest Client
    $client = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);

    // Step 4: make an array of people we know, to send them a message. 
    // Feel free to change/add your own phone number and name here.
    $people = array(
        "+44463463241" => "Andrew Charlton",
    );

    // Step 5: Loop over all our friends. $number is a phone number above, and 
    // $name is the name next to it
    foreach ($people as $number => $name) {

        $sms = $client->account->messages->sendMessage(

        // Step 6: Change the 'From' number below to be a valid Twilio number 
        // that you've purchased, or the (deprecated) Sandbox number
            "YYY-YYY-YYYY", 

            // the number we are sending to - Any phone number
            +44463463241,

            // the sms body
            "Hey $name, Monkey Party at 6PM. Bring Bananas!"
        );

        // Display a confirmation message on the screen
        echo "Sent message to $name";
    }


    }
```

I've left my account ID and authtoken out of the above.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you use `require`.
According to the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) and the one of [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) the require opens a file and evals the code behind it.
what it does in the way you use it, is the following: fetch the file from  http://xzenweb.co.uk/reservation/web/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php (whitch returns nothing at all) and evals id (evals nothing).
This is why your require fails.

If you want to require/include that piece of coe, you should download the sourcecode from http://xzenweb.co.uk/reservation/web/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php and put it in the environment of your code.

Bit if i understand Twilio right, they are used as an rest webservice.
Accodring to the documentaton http://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/sending-messages
you want to download the rest-client-code (like described here https://www.twilio.com/docs/php/install) and then it all come to you ;-)

Comment: Thanks for this, I have installed the php under the service sub directory but I'm still receiving the error

Comment: did you fix the path in ther require? require(__DIR__.'/my/path/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php')?
You need to adjust the path, but starting from this example you should be able to get it done.

Comment: __DIR__ should be with two underscores before and after ...
like described here : http://php.net/manual/de/language.constants.predefined.php